# How to properly implement a Services class into my iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, architecture, afnetworking

My current head scratcher: implementing a model class specifically for service calls to my rails application.

Here is the scenario:

- I have a class named **Service** that is a subclass of NSObject.
- The implementation file has a few methods defined… lets look at
  *doSignUp*.
- I am using **AFNetworking** to communicate with the api.
- From my **SignUpViewController**, I create an instance of my
  **Service** class and call *doSignUp*
- The method works, as expected and I receive the proper response from the server.

Now Comes the part I don't fully understand:

- **AFNetworking** utilizes blocks for its service calls.
- Inside the *success* block I call a helper method called *handleSignUp* (also in **Service** class). This method essentially parses the JSON and I create a new **User** (NSObject subclass) out of it. The *handSignUp* method then returns the **User** object.

At this point I have a new **User** object and I need to send that object back to my **SignUpViewController**... How can I do that?

- Should I try to add that object to the **AppDelegate** and access it
  from the **SignUpViewController**? This solution could work to access
  various global properties but when would the **SignUpViewController**
  know when to access it?
- Should I try to add a reference to the **SignUpViewController** in
  the **Service** class? That seems counter productive... I might as
  well add the method *doSignUp* and *handSignUp* to the
  **SignUpViewController**. It seems to me like my **Service** class should not be aware of any other viewControllers.

See below for my code examples:

Service.h

```
//Service.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AFNetworking.h"
@interface Services : NSObject
- (void) doSignUp:(NSMutableDictionary*)params;
@end
```

Service.m

```
// Service.m
 #import "Services.h"
 #import "Config.h"
 @implementation Services

 - (void) doSignUp:(NSMutableDictionary*)params {
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MYURL.COM"];
     AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
     NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"signup.json" parameters:params];
     AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
         [self handleSignUp:JSON];
     } failure:nil];
     [operation start];
 }

 - (User*) handleSignUp:(NSMutableArray*)json {
     User * user = nil;
     if ([[json valueForKey:@"success"] isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
           // create user here ...
     }
     return user;
 }
```

SignUpViewController.h

```
#import "Service.h"
 @interface SignUpViewController : UIViewController {
     Service * service;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, strong) Service * service;
```

SignUpViewController.m

```
#import "SignUpViewController.h"
 @interface SignUpViewController ()
 @end

 @implementation SignUpViewController

 @synthesize service = __service;
 - (IBAction) initSignUp:(id)sender {
      // create params...
      [self.service doSignUp:params];
 }
```

Again, all this code does what it is supposed to do... I just need to know how it should all communicate. How can I alert the **SignUpViewController** the *handleSignUp* has been called and a new **User** object is available?

Thanks for your time,
Andre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i can see you are not realizing the asynchronous nature of this process: actually since network or IO operations take a long time to complete we tend to prefer asynchronous access, i mean: the caller (View Controller) calls a message on the web API through the service and then STOPS WAITING FOR A RESPONSE. Actually the network processing could be done on a different process or thread or processor's core.

Now then, how can the caller BE NOTIFIED by the service when the operation completes?
For this to happen we must bind the two objects using Delegation: 
we create a protocol (it's just a declaration of messages that an object will be responding to)  and we implement it in our View Controller, that way whoever will be using it will know for sure what messages are available.

Then we will declare a delegate of type id in our service that will be called once the operations will be completed.

It's almost like importing your ViewController.h in the service class and giving the service a pointer to the view controller, but done in the right way (without circular references and respecting SOLID principles)

Now some code:

```
//service.h
@protocol RemoteApiProtocol <NSObject>
@required
-(void) UserLoggingIn;
-(void) UserLoggedIn:(User*)user;
-(void) UserLoginError:(NSError *)error;
@end
```

The protocol works like a small interface, it's a contract between two classes/objects.
Then in your service you can declare field & property for the protocol:

```
//Service.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AFNetworking.h"
@interface Services : NSObject{
      __weak id<RemoteApiProtocol> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<RemoteApiProtocol> delegate;

- (void) doSignUp:(NSMutableDictionary*)params;

@end
```

At this point you implement the protocol in your view controller, integrating the contract you just build. This way the server will know that the delegate will always be able to respond to the protocol messages.

```
//SignUpViewController.h
#import "Service.h"
 @interface SignUpViewController : UIViewController <RemoteApiProtocol> {
     Service * service;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, strong) Service * service;
```

After implementing the protocol you can assign your view controller as delegate for the server, this way the server, after calling the apis will be able to call the delegate with the result of the call. For this to happen you implement the protocols messages that will be called by the service:

```
//SignUpViewController.m
#import "SignUpViewController.h"

 @implementation SignUpViewController

 @synthesize service = __service;
 - (IBAction) initSignUp:(id)sender {
      //create the service with params
      //...

      //assign self as the delegate
      self.service.delegate = self;
      [self.service doSignUp:params];
 }

#pragma mark - RemoteApiProtocol
-(void) UserLoggingIn
{
      //login started, 
      //you can show a spinner or animation here
}
-(void) UserLoggedIn:(User*)user
{
      //user logged in , do your stuff here
}
-(void) UserLoginError:(NSError *)error
{
      NSLog(@"error: %@",error);
}

@end
```

And finally you call the messages in your service, after calling the apis in the success and error block:

```
// Service.m
 #import "Services.h"
 #import "Config.h"
 @implementation Services

 - (void) doSignUp:(NSMutableDictionary*)params {
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MYURL.COM"];
     AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
     NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"signup.json" parameters:params];
     AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
         [self handleSignUp:JSON];
     } failure:nil];


     //Signaling the start of the signup operation to the delegate
     if(self.delegate){
          [self.delegate UserLoggingIn];
     }

     [operation start];
 }

 - (User*) handleSignUp:(NSMutableArray*)json {
     User * user = nil;
     if ([[json valueForKey:@"success"] isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
           // create user here ...
           //call the delegate (view controller) passing the user
           if(self.delegate){
               [self.delegate UserLoggedIn:user];
           }
     }else{
           //error handling
           if(self.delegate){
               //NSError *error = ...
               //[self.delegate UserLoginError:error];
           }
     }


     //return user;
 }
@end
```

Comment: This method worked very well, however, @mattt had [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11018105/833830) using blocks because it was easier. Both solutions work great but I am curious to know what the pros or cons of the suggested solutions might be. Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't mentioned Blocks because they are easier o use, but not easier to understand.

What i saw here was a need to understand clearly the (asynchronous) process instead of more concise code.

Speaking of delegates is like describing an human interaction, where someone asks something to someone else and then waits for a response. 

Describing blocks, closures and lambda functions is not as easy.

Comment: Got it. I decided to go with your suggested method and you're correct, it is easier to understand that process. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into `Delegation` and or a `Data Source`. Check my accepted answer in this post for an example, and reference to Apple Docs on the subject.

[Objective C View to Controller Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941177/objective-c-view-to-controller-communication/10941216#10941216)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add callback block parameters to the `doSignUp` (should probably be renamed to `signUpWithParams:success:failure:`), so that the controller can respond to the signup succeeding or failing, and having the context for either case available to present relevant information to the user.

Comment: Would you suggest this method over creating a @protocol. If so, why?

Comment: Wait, what? Do you mean a delegate? No, definitely use blocks—much, much easier.

Comment: Yes, I mean creating a Delegate. So if I understand correctly, my _doSignUp_ (or _signUpWithParams_) method would contain callback block params **AND** include the AFJSONRequestOperation block... which also contains success:fail params. Is there an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

The delegation method would definitely work.  You could basically add a delegate to the Service class, and set the delegate equal to the view controller before calling doSignup.

However, I would implement it using blocks.  Add a parameter to the doSignUp method which is a completion block, which is declared in the SignUpViewController.  For an example of how to pass blocks as parameters, just check out the source from AFNetworking.